# How to pass string with spaces pyspark arguments in spark-on-k8s-operator

Tags: apache-spark, airflow

One of the pyspark arg is sql query (string with spaces).
I tried to pass it as - `\"select * from table\"` and  `"select * from table"`

But it's not treated it as a whole string and `select *` bash command is getting executed which is corrupting the SQL.

Example: Above query got converted as -  `\"select' folder1 file1.zip from 'table\"`

Driver Logs:

```
PYSPARK_ARGS=
+ '[' -n 'process  --query \"select * from table\"' ']'
+ PYSPARK_ARGS='process --query \"select * from table\"'
+ R_ARGS=
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' 3 == 2 ']'
+ '[' 3 == 3 ']'
++ python3 -V
+ pyv3='Python 3.7.3'
+ export PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.3
+ PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.3
+ export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
+ PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
+ export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3
+ PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3
+ case "$SPARK_K8S_CMD" in
+ CMD=("$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit" --conf "spark.driver.bindAddress=$SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS" --deploy-mode client "$@" $PYSPARK_PRIMARY $PYSPARK_ARGS)
+ exec /usr/bin/tini -s -- /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.driver.bindAddress=xx.xx.xx.xx --deploy-mode client --class org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner file:/usr/local/bin/process_sql.py process 
--query '\"select' folder1 file1.zip from 'table\"'
```

Is there a way to safely pass string argument with spaces, single or double quotes?

Comment: You can try to set variable `QUERY="select * from table"`, then use it in your command: `--query "$QUERY"`